# Opening Excel with many columns

Tags: excel, multiple-columns

Basically, I have an Excel 2003 spreadsheet that I wish to open.
However, it is giving error because it has too many columns.

What is a way of opening this Excel file to view the entire data?

PS. I have Excel 2010 installed as well but unable to open that file.

Additional info: The Excel file is created using SSRS -> Export to Excel. The number of columns in the report varies and when large report range is chosen, it will have "too many" columns.

Comment: This is not matter for SO unless you are opening it via VBA. How exactly are you opening it ?

Comment: I have added more info in my post. Basically, the Excel file is created by SSRS Export to Excel function and it created fairly large number of columns. I wish to open up the Excel file somehow by overcoming this issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you have more than 256 columns you won't be able to use versions of Excel prior to 2007.

It sounds like you're exporting to a pre-2007 workbook (xls) with more than that number.

in 2007+ you can have around 16 thousand columns.

This page has details about how to export to a 2007+ file format (xlsx):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255234(v=sql.110).aspx

**Note** I think your SQL server may need to be a certain version to use the 2007+ excel renderer, but I have little experience there.